# Round image inside div

Tags: css

The objective is to put one image in div tag, and make the corner image round.
Here is my code:

```
   <div id="round-div">
   <a href="#1"  class="cross-link active-thumb">
   <img src="<%: HelperClass.CheckImageUrlExist(Model.GetItemSpecial[0].PictureName) %>" alt="<%: Model.GetItemSpecial[0].Name %>" width="63px" height="36px" class="nav-thumb"/>
   </a>
   </div>
```

Comment: first of all, you should go back and accept answers to your previous questions.  Secondly, this doesn't seem to be attempting round corners at all.  What have you tried and what is your css?  This information is necessary in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the image be the background image of the div tag and then use the css property: `border-radius:10px;` That would round it for you. You could also just add the property to the image as well.

```
.round-div img 
{
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
}
```